# Initial CV::MAT from a float array representing RGB image

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv, mat

Introduction to my problem:
I have serialized myself a `CV::MAT` object in c++ and sent in to a python program (more accurately, I have a python program that uses a c++ .exe as subprocess..), I deserialize it in python back into a 2D array of (R,G,B) ints

Now I have a different method in my python service that on demand sends this 2D array back to the c++ process and have it do something
I DONT want to use boost serializer because its basically hell
I have serialized it myself from python and manage to give the c++ process a flattened array along with the dimentions of the 2D array (rows and cols)

Now I have no idea how I construct a `CV::MAT` object back from this data
i know there's `Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)` which might do the job but no idea what goes insize the step in case its what I think it is

Any help would be highly appreciated!

This is the c++ code I have so far

```
    vector<string> imgVector;
    int imgRows = stoi(kp.at(7));
    int imgCols = stoi(kp.at(8));
    split(kp.at(2), ' ', back_inserter(imgVector)); // kp.at(2) is a ' ' seperated array of integers
    int* pixels = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * imgVector.size());
    for (int j = 0; (unsigned)j < imgVector.size(); i++){
        pixels[j] = stoi(imgVector[j]);
    }
    Mat image(imgRows, imgCols, CV_32F, pixels);
```

But I think it will make a 2D array of integers and not of RGB tuples like I want

Comment: You need a `CV_8UC3` image (not CV_32F). The buffer `pixels` should be a `uchar*`, with length `rows*cols*3` (3 channels).

Comment: im confused, if pixels will be of type uchar* how can it be of length rows*cols*3? each number is takes more than 1 byte (which is uchar).

Comment: got it. i should convert the string i have into uchar characters which will represent the colors? because uchar can give me 0-255? but then how do i convert the string i have "255 255 255 249..." to an array of uchar?

Comment: Yes, a pixel is a triplet (3 channels) BGR (In OpenCV the convention is BGR, not RGB), where each channel is in range [0,255]

Comment: uchar(stoi(...)). Or better `cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(stoi(...))`

Comment: its working! thank you!!!!

Comment: got a suggestion of what to do if i want to do the same thing only with a 2D array of floats? not RGB pixels. the the length is just rows*cols of floats. uchar cant contain that

Comment: Same as before, type CV_32FC3, pixels is float* of size (rows* cols* 3), stof(...). For single channel images, CV_32FC1, size(rows*cols)

Comment: amazing. thank you! saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected items:

- You need the type to be `CV_8UC3` to store a 3-channel int array.
- The size of the mat should be rows*cols*3.
- The data type per pixel should be `uchar`.

Following those, the following code should work.

```
vector<string> imgVector;
int imgRows = stoi(kp.at(7));
int imgCols = stoi(kp.at(8));
split(kp.at(2), ' ', back_inserter(imgVector)); // kp.at(2) is a ' ' seperated array of integers
uchar* pixels = (uchar*)malloc(sizeof(uchar) * imgRows*imgCols*3);
for (int j = 0; (unsigned)j < imgVector.size(); i++){
    pixels[j] = uchar(stoi(imgVector[j]));
}
Mat image(imgRows, imgCols, CV_8UC3, pixels);
```

Comment: Miki has already helped me via the comments but this is also a great answer, thank you!